# How can I retrieve a non-cached page using requests-html?

Tags: python, caching, python-requests-html

I'm trying to scrape a page with the following code using requests-html:

```
session = HTMLSession()
resp = session.get(url,
                   headers={"Cache-Control": "private, max-age=0, no-cache",
                            "Pragma": "no-cache",
                            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:92.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/92.0"})
```

but it randomly gives me a cached page with incorrect content.  I copied the User-Agent string from my browser, which never shows me incorrect data on this site because of caching.  What else do I have to do to get a fresh page?

Comment: Depends completely on the site you are sending your request to. Could be impossible though.

Comment: But if it's possible for the browser to always retrieve the correct page, it should be possible, right?

Comment: Please read the first part of my earlier comment again!

Comment: So there's no way to exactly replicate what the browser is sending, without being the browser?  That doesn't really make any sense.  The browser is just a program, surely I should be able to do anything the browser is doing in code.